# Adding feature to GeoServer vector layer using WFS-T in absence of fid index?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, vector, wfs-t

I want to add a feature to GeoServer vector layer with WFS-T.

When I use saveStrategy.save(), an error returned that said:

> java.io.IOException: current fid index is null, next must be called before write().

How can I add a geometric feature to GeoServer vector layer without fill feature fid?

Comment: what is backing the datastore you are writing to? if it is a database then do you have a primary key set?

Comment: Which datastore you have behind the WFS feature type? Shapefile, PostGIS, something else? If it is PostGIS, how does the schema look like? Error has something to do with acquiring a new unique fid for the new feature. It can be picked from autoincrementing field, from a separate trigger or from calculating max(fid)+1 if datastore does not support the two first alternatives.